# how to run vbox in seamless mode?

Tags: virtualbox

Im using windows xp sp2. and I want to emulate ubuntu 10.04 using virtualbox, can I make use of seamless mode in here? I've already installed the guest additions.

Comment: Do you have Compiz enabled ? Try disabling that.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can have both XP and Linux on the same disk, by using Linux as an application within Windows. This way, you don't disturb XP at all.

I suggest the Wubi linux distribution, since it's a variant of the very popular and easy to use Ubuntu Linux:

[**Wubi**](http://wubi-installer.org/) -- an officially supported Ubuntu installer for Windows

[image]

Comment: how does Wubi enable seemless mode in virtualbox???

Comment: Sorry, this isn't an answer to the question. -1

Comment: Wubi is the simplest way to have Ubuntu on Windows. Much simpler to install and use than VirtualBox. And MUCH more "seamless". I recommend this over VirtualBox, no matter what.

Comment: I we aren't allowed to give more advice than was strictly asked for, what's the point in being on superuser.com?

Comment: @ephilip: It seems like this IS the answer to the question.